# SQL (sqlite) compare sums of rows grouped by another repeating row

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sum

I have a table like:

```
|------------------------|  
|day  name  trees_planted|  
|------------------------|  
|1  | alice |  3         |  
|2  | alice |  4         |  
|1  | bob   |  2         |  
|2  | bob   |  4         |  
|------------------------|
```

I'm using `SELECT name, SUM(trees_planted) FROM year2016 GROUP BY name` to get:

```
name  | trees_planted  
alice | 7  
bob   | 6
```

But then I have another table from 2015 and I want to compare the results with the previous year, if for example Alice planted more trees in 2016 than in 2015 I'd get a result like this:

```
name  | tree_difference  
alice | -2 (if previous year she planted 5 trees, 5 -7 = -2)  
bob   | 0 (planted the same number of trees last year)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can join using `user` field, you can do:

```
select a.name, a.tp, b.tp, a.tp - b.tp
  from 
   (
      (select name, SUM(trees_planted) tp from year2016 group by name) a
     inner join
      (select name, SUM(trees_planted) tp from year2015 group by name) b
     using(name)
   )
```

If you can't join on field `user` (you have different set of users in 2015 and 2016), it'll be easy to add the missing information by using a couple of `union` clauses.

Here's a link with artificial data to [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/56508/1/0) to try the query.

Comment: Hey, it worked, I don't understand exactly why but I will play around with pieces from your answer and see if I get it, I also have to look up the 'using' keyword, first time I see it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it worked @userian. Take a look at trincot answer also. It has a different approach, but it might work for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sub-query to get the records from both 2016 and 2015, but negate the values from 2016. Then group and sum like you already did:

```
SELECT    name, 
          SUM(trees_planted) AS tree_difference
FROM      (SELECT name, trees_planted 
           FROM   year2015
           UNION ALL
           SELECT name, -trees_planted
           FROM   year2016
          ) AS years
GROUP BY  name
```

This will also work for cases where a number is only given in one of the two years.

Comment: Hm, this works too and after running only the part with the "UNION ALL" I see why, I only knew about UNION and first time I wrote this in the terminal I got zero as the difference because I missed the ALL. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the `ALL` is needed, as otherwise "duplicates" get eliminated, but that would be an undesired effect in this case. Note that if for some person you only have data in 2015 and not in 2016, you will still get a result for that person. Same for when you only have data in 2016.